# html form action to class function

Tags: php, forms, class

I have a html form that executes login and I have a php file that is a class that has a function to check login.  I want the form action to go to that function on the class that checks the login but I don't know how to do that.

For now the form action links to another php file and that php file goes to the class function.

Is there a way to make the action on the form directs to the class function without having a file in between?

It works but I think that is unnecessary to have a file with just 3-4 lines.

Comment: You can't make form to go to the specific PHP class or function. You need to intercept the request you're making from the form and simply call desired code.

Answer (score 1):

In one file store all your classes and include them into controller file which serves as communicator between your user and classes.
So for example when you send user log information, you can create class object in controller and pass your variables(username, password) into it's functions :)
**controller.php**

```
include_once("classes.php");
$Username = $_POST["Username"];
$Password = $_POST["Password"];
$Validate = new Validation($Username, $Password); // Create Object
    $Validate->validate(); //Calls object's validation function
```

**UPDATE:**
Make form action equal to classes.php

classes.php

```
Class Validation
{
    //Here starts your class methods and parameters.
}

$Username = $_POST["Username"];
$Password = $_POST["Password"];

//Initialize your class in same file
$Validation = new Validation($Username, $Password); // Create object

$Validation->function(); //Object's functions
```

Comment: i'm not using mvc...i understand what you're saying because i work in mvc but when i started this project i didn't know mvc so i'm finishing it without using mvc

Comment: It's not MVC, to use class and it's functions you need to create object. So first of all you should create Object and only after that you will be able to pass your variables to functions :)

Comment: i have what you put above but the problem is that i don't know what to put in action=" "

Comment: controller.php or any kind of file where you will include your class file. I wrote it as controller.php because i thought it would be the best way to understand the problem, if it's comfortable for you call it index2.php or server.php :)

Comment: Just understood what you were trying to say. I already have that controller.php. is that file that i said that was in between. on it i have  include("class.php");
  $my = new class();
  $my->login($_POST['user'],$_POST['password']);    it works...what i was trying to do was don't have this file because is small and redirect to function without having a controller in between but it looks like there isn't a way

Comment: Check out Answer post again :)